# What happen if an input stream is sent to an output stream?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, input

What happen if an input stream is sent to an output stream? 
Is it possible
Can you help me with an example in c + +

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: [`std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();`](http://ideone.com/oVp83T)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean something like this:

```
std::cout << std::cin;
```

Yes, you can do that. Depending on whether you are using a C++03 or C++11 compliant compiler, it will do different things:

- C++03: It will print out the return value of `std::cin.operator void *()`
- C++11: It will print out the return value of `std::cin.operator bool()`

It will not automatically copy the results of the input stream to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an input stream to an output stream is known as a pipe.

Yes, you can do it.